# Is your son climbing onto that table? vs Is that your son climbing onto that table?

Tags: meaning

Do these sentences mean the same?

**Is your son climbing onto that table?**

and

**Is that your son climbing onto that table?**

I think they are different. The first is asking about the action but the later is asking about who. But in Rosetta stone there is an example:

> **Is your son climbing onto that table? No, that’s not my son.**

Is this example correct?

Comment: What do you think? Please explain IN the question if you think the two sentences are interchangeable or not, and why.

Comment: No, the first is asking asking **what** is going on. The second is asking, do  you know **who** it is.

Comment: @Mari-LouA I think they are different. The first is asking about the action but the later is asking about who. But in Rosetta stone there is an example: <<Is your son climbing onto that table? No, that’s not my son>>. Is this example correct?

Comment: IN the question, please. Not in comments that very few will bother reading.

Comment: The second question is ostensibly asking about the identity of a person, adding the identifier '[the person who is] climbing onto the specified table'. It can reasonably be answered "Yes / no / I can't quite tell ...". However, it is quite possibly largely rhetorical, anticipating a dash over to the table to stop this grave misdemeanour, rather than a verbal response. // The first is also possibly largely rhetorical. A verbal response is of course possible: "The little ...". However, the asker may ...

Comment: in both cases be in ignorance of whether or not the climber _is_ actually the son of the person asked, and a "No[, ...]' response is far from unreasonable. This is a less likely scenario with the first variant, where the paraphrase "Your son is climbing onto that table! You'd better ..." is pretty likely to be accurate.

Answer (score 2):

'Is your son climbing onto that table?' means that you have identified the son and are asking confirmation of what he is doing.

'Is that your son climbing onto that table?' means that you see someone's son climbing onto a table but aren't sure whose son he is.

'That's not my son' is a valid answer to both; so is 'He's not climbing onto the table';  and so is both 'Yes' and 'No'.

Comment: "Is your son..." does not mean one has identified the son. Indeed―looking only at the words―the first question does not presuppose anyone is climbing on that table at all.  Or that if someone is climbing on that table that it is a boy, or anyone's son or even human.  In the context of Rosetta Stone though there is usually an accompanying picture that guides the conversation.  Sometimes, particularly further in to the program, the picture prompts the user to express nuance―such as by presenting a picture of a *girl* climbing on a table and asking "is your son climbing onto that table?"

Answer (score 0):

The two statements are likely to elicit similar responses from the same person in the same set of circumstances.  But they do have slightly different meanings.

**Is your son climbing onto that table?**

This question asks whether a certain person (your son) is taking a certain action (climbing) in relation to a certain thing (that table).

**Is that your son climbing onto that table?**

This one asks whether some person who is taking a certain action (climbing) in relation to a certain thing (that table) is in fact your son.

The Rosetta Stone example is a correct example of a meaningful, conversational exchange in this situation:

[image: boy climbing on table]

<sub>[Source](https://www.flickr.com/photos/timlauer/36966090746/). Used with permission per CC BY-NC 2.0</sub>

> Is your son climbing onto that table?
>
> No, that’s not my son.

The reply asserts that the statement form of the question asked is false:

> Your son is climbing onto that table.

And it explains why it is false. There is a table and someone's son is climbing onto it. But it's not the respondent's son.

Comment: @Mari-LouA I don't know how I didn't see that line.  Though it is a holiday morning after a long night. =)  I'll expand in a bit.